# RPA calculations with Hybrid Functionals

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, software, random-phase-approximation

When doing RPA calculations [as explained here](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/ACFDT/RPA_calculations), if I want to calculate it with hybrid PBE0 should I put `LHFCALC = .TRUE.` for just step 1 or step 1, step 3 and step 4?

Comment: Hi, you can also check the input files provided at https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/Equilibrium_volume_of_Si_in_the_RPA . My guess is that PBE0 calculation is only done at step 2, so you need only set ‘LHFCALC = .TRUE.’ at at this step.

Comment: This uses PBE orbitals and that’s why it doesn’t use it at step 1 3 and 4. Step2 is different. It’s just for hartree fock energy. So you already need to use it there

Comment: Note PBE0 is a hybrid functional. I'm not sure there is a standard definition of hybrid orbitals.

Comment: To my knowledge, adding LHFCALC = .TRUE. in a INCAR with POTCAR for PBE, it calculates for PBE0. Or am I wrong?

Comment: To reply to a particular user in the comments, you need to ping them like this `@mykd`. You will always be notified of comments since this is your question.

Comment: @mykd OP didn't ping you, so I'm not sure if you saw their most recent comment.

Comment: @Tyberius I saw it, but I was waiting for the OP to respond to your query, as that will clarify their target calculation setup.

Comment: This post appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.

Comment: @TauschenOkay, The question could be edited to give some more detail, including used input files. This way we could try to answer in clearer way.